# Trouble accessing a JavaScript array member due to complex key name

Tags: javascript

I have a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)array:

```
{
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin",
  "nbf": 1512187433,
  "exp": 1512187453,
  "iss": "SuperAwesomeTokenServer",
  "aud": "http://localhost:3000/"
}
```

The first key is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"` for which its value is "Admin".

I would like to access this key but am having trouble using the key name due to the fact its an href instead of a single name.

How would I access the value `"Admin"`? I wanted to use say `myArray.role` etc. but the name role is at the end of a very long `href` with a number of slashes etc.

I wanted to know the best way to access it and can't find anything on StackOverflow save splitting. It would be nice to access based on the key name.

Comment: This works for me: `obj["http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"]`

Comment: If it's an array, you can't use dot notation `myArray.role`, this is just when you are into an object, for the array you'd bracket notation, like @Mark_M says `obj["http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims‌/role"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it:

```js
var obj = {
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin",
  "nbf": 1512187433,
  "exp": 1512187453,
  "iss": "SuperAwesomeTokenServer",
  "aud": "http://localhost:3000/"
}



console.log(obj["http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `obj.key` if and only if the identifier does not contain any special char *(Except _)*. So if you want to get the Result for URI like the key you can use the array key notation for fetching data.

```
var variable = {
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin",
  "nbf": 1512187433,
  "exp": 1512187453,
  "iss": "SuperAwesomeTokenServer",
  "aud": "http://localhost:3000/"
};

//When key heaving the special char can be done like only.
console.log(variable["http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"]); // Admin

// But if the key isn't contained special char that can be used in both ways.For Example:

console.log(variable["nbf"]); // 1512187433
console.log(variable.nbf); // 1512187433
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for the first or second key/value. It may be because of the back/forward slashes in the key name.

Comment: Yes, i also highlight this in my answer.