# Searching within a key name of an array for name and recovering that keys value

Tags: javascript

I got a great answer to [MY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604496/trouble-accessing-a-javascript-array-member-due-to-complex-key-name#47604571) question on accessing complex key names values however its occurred to me that I may not be able to rely on the total complex name of that key - it might change - however I am confident in the last word in the key name namely "role".

The array is as follows - as taken from the console:

```
{
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin",
  "nbf": 1512187433,
  "exp": 1512187453,
  "iss": "SuperAwesomeTokenServer",
  "aud": "http://localhost:3000/"
}
```

I cant rely on the href to be the same except for the name "role" and I cannot rely on the fact its currently sitting in first spot.

How would I Check all key names for the existence of "role" buried in the name and then return the key's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
var data = {
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin",
  "nbf": 1512187433,
  "exp": 1512187453,
  "iss": "SuperAwesomeTokenServer",
  "aud": "http://localhost:3000/"
};

for(var key in data){
  if(key.includes('role')){
    console.log(data[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below loops through the object and returns an array where the key contains 'role'.

```js
var obj = {
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin",
  "nbf": 1512187433,
  "exp": 1512187453,
  "iss": "SuperAwesomeTokenServer",
  "aud": "http://localhost:3000/"
};

  var arr = [];
for(var key in obj){
  if(key.indexOf('role') !== -1){
    arr.push(obj[key])
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```